# Request web Page on Glassfish server using java code

Tags: java, glassfish, request

am trying to read web page from java code and its fine for general web site like google.com but when using the same code to read page on glassfish server at my computer i have this error:-

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL: http://jedsms02:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at reader.ReadSMS.main(ReadSMS.java:195)
```

and this is my code:-

```
String urlString =
       "http://localhost:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp"
    try {
        URL url;
        url = new URL(urlString);            
        Scanner in = new Scanner(url.openStream());
        while (in.hasNext())
            System.out.println(in.nextLine());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I had change the URL by replace the localhost to IP "192.120.20.167" but i get this error

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://192.120.20.167:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp?Number=0xxxxxxxxx&Message= Test Man
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at reader.ReadSMS.main(ReadSMS.java:195)
```

Please help,
thank you

Comment: What happens when you open that url yourself, i.e. put it into the browsers address bar (clear the cache first to ensure you don't get a different result because of the cache)? What does the server say upon receiving that request?

Comment: its work fine in browser

Comment: Sorry the error i was posted was wrong this is the error stack

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 406 for URL: http://jedsms02:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
 at reader.ReadSMS.main(ReadSMS.java:195)

Comment: Most probably you get an unexpected mime type, i.e. nothing the client would accept. Could you post the accept headers of connection?

Comment: I had change the url to the server IP then i get this error

    java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://192.120.20.167:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp?Number=0xxxxxxxxx&Message= Test Man
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
 at reader.ReadSMS.main(ReadSMS.java:195)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a 505 because your request parameters are not encoded. Use URLEncoder to encode your parameters, e.g.

```
URLEncoder.encode(" Test Man", "utf8");
```

The URL then becomes

http://192.120.20.167:8080/Mirnint_Library-Mirnint_Message-context-root/Sending.jsp?Number=0xxxxxxxxx&Message=%20Test%20Man